# Performance of runif

Tags: c++, r, memory, rcpp

I am working on a custom bootstrap algorithm for a specific problem, and as I want a large number of replicates I do care about performance. In this regard, I have some questions on how to use runif properly. I'm aware that I could run benchmarks myself, but C++ optimization tends to be difficult and I would also like to understand the reasons for any difference.

First question:

Is the first code block faster than the second?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n_boot; i++) {
  new_random = runif(n);  //new_random is pre-allocated in class
  // do something with the random numbers
}
```

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < n_boot; i++) {
  NumericVector new_random = runif(n);
  // do something with the random numbers
}
```

It probably comes down to whether runif fills the left side or if it allocates and passes a new NumericVector.

Second question:

If both versions allocate a new vector, can I improve things by generating one random number at a time in scalar mode?

In case you are wondering, memory allocation takes up a sizable part of my processing time. I have reduced runtime by 30% by optimizing other unnecessary memory allocations away, so it does matter.

Comment: you should try this question on codereview http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Sharky On Code Review, the only reasonable answer to the question would be "benchmark it!". The question itself is likely to be closed because of being example code. I think Erik would benefit more from a benchmark than a Code Review. And by the way, Erik: From my experience, there's absolutely no difference in the performance of those code snippets.

Comment: You completely miss the point _that each draw at the end of the day is a scalar draw against the C API of R_ so where the looping happens is largely irrelevant _as far as performance_ is concerned.  Rcpp Sugar makes use easier.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel No, I don't miss that point. I know that the loop does not matter and I don't want to optimize the time used to actually generate the random numbers. What I want to avoid is an unnecessary memory allocation of a NumericVector. Maybe the question is not formulated cleary enough. It comes down to whether there is a way to directly write the new random numbers in my already allocated vector without allocating and initializing a new one.

Comment: Profile.  Profile.  Profile.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel OK, I was going to do so. But whatever comes out, I would still like to understand why ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I set up the following `struct` to try to represent your scenario accurately & facilitate the benchmarking:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

struct runif_test {

  size_t runs;
  size_t each;

  runif_test(size_t runs, size_t each)
  : runs(runs), each(each)
  {}
  // Your first code block
  void pre_init() {
    Rcpp::NumericVector v = no_init();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
      v = Rcpp::runif(each);
    }
  }
  // Your second code block
  void post_init() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
      Rcpp::NumericVector v = Rcpp::runif(each);
    }
  }
  // Generate 1 draw at a time  
  void gen_runif() {
    Rcpp::NumericVector v = no_init();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
      std::generate_n(v.begin(), each, []() -> double {
        return Rcpp::as<double>(Rcpp::runif(1));
      });
    }
  }
  // Reduce overhead of pre-allocated vector
  inline Rcpp::NumericVector no_init() {
    return Rcpp::NumericVector(Rcpp::no_init_vector(each));
  } 
};
```

---

where I benchmarked the following exported functions:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void do_pre(size_t runs, size_t each) {
  runif_test obj(runs, each);
  obj.pre_init();
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void do_post(size_t runs, size_t each) {
  runif_test obj(runs, each);
  obj.post_init();
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void do_gen(size_t runs, size_t each) {
  runif_test obj(runs, each);
  obj.gen_runif();
}
```

---

Here are the results I got:

```
R>  microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    do_pre(100, 10e4)
    ,do_post(100, 10e4)
    ,do_gen(100, 10e4)
    ,times=100L)
Unit: milliseconds
                 expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
  do_pre(100, 100000) 109.9187 125.0477  145.9918 136.3749  152.9609  337.6143   100
 do_post(100, 100000) 103.1705 117.1109  132.9389 130.4482  142.7319  204.0951   100
  do_gen(100, 100000) 810.5234 911.3586 1005.9438 986.8348 1062.7715 1501.2933   100
```

---

```
R>  microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    do_pre(100, 10e5)
    ,do_post(100, 10e5)
    ,times=100L)
Unit: seconds
                  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
  do_pre(100, 1000000) 1.355160 1.614972 1.740807 1.723704 1.815953 2.408465   100
 do_post(100, 1000000) 1.198667 1.342794 1.443391 1.429150 1.519976 2.042511   100
```

---

So, assuming I interpreted / accurately represented your second question,

> If both versions allocate a new vector, can I improve things by
>   generating one random number at a time in scalar mode?

with my `gen_runif()` member function, I think we can confidently say that this is not the optimal approach - ~ 7.5x slower than the other two functions.

More importantly, to address your first question, it seems that it is a little faster to just initialize & assign a new `NumericVector` to the output of `Rcpp::runif(n)`. I'm certainly no C++ expert, but I believe the second method (assigning to a new local object) was faster than the first because of [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). In the second case, it *looks* as though two objects are being created - the object on the left of the `=`, `v`, and a (temporary? rvalue?) object on the right side of the `=`, which is the result of `Rcpp::runif()`. In reality though, the compiler will most likely optimize this unnecessary step out - which I think is explained in this passage from the article I linked:

> When a nameless temporary, not bound to any references, would be moved
>   or copied into an object of the same type ... the copy/move is omitted. When that temporary is
>   constructed, it is constructed directly in the storage where it would
>   otherwise be moved or copied to.

This was, at least, how I interpreted the results. Hopefully someone who is more well-versed in the language can confirm / deny / correct this conclusion.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. And even though it is not optimal, I didn`t know about the no_init option.

Comment: @Erik I fear you may still be shooting for the wrong targets.  But as you seem to have such firm beliefs about what ought to be faster, maybe you would want to provide an alternate implementation?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel The not optimal was not a criticism the implementation in Rcpp, instead I refered to the pre_init function using the no_init() option. I am now very content with using what is basically do_post. Thanks for the Rcpp package by the way, it is extremly useful to the R-package I am currently working on (fbroc).

Answer (score 3):

Adding to to @nrussell's answer with some implementation details...

*Use the source, Luke!* definitely applies here, so let's look at the implementation of `Rcpp::runif` [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/stats/random/random.h#L301-L305):

```
inline NumericVector runif( int n, double min, double max ){
    if (!R_FINITE(min) || !R_FINITE(max) || max < min) return NumericVector( n, R_NaN ) ;
    if( min == max ) return NumericVector( n, min ) ;
    return NumericVector( n, stats::UnifGenerator( min, max ) ) ;
}
```

We see that an interesting constructor of `NumericVector` is being called with a `stats::UnifGenerator` object. That class's definition is [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/stats/random/runif.h#L29-L44):

```
    class UnifGenerator__0__1 : public ::Rcpp::Generator<double> {
    public:

        UnifGenerator__0__1() {}

        inline double operator()() const {
            double u;
            do {u = unif_rand();} while (u <= 0 || u >= 1);
            return u;
        }
    } ;
```

So, that class just a functor -- it implements `operator()` and so objects of that class can be 'called'.

Finally, the associated `NumericVector` constructor is [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h#L147-L152):

```
template <typename U>
Vector( const int& size, const U& u) {
    RCPP_DEBUG_2( "Vector<%d>( const int& size, const U& u )", RTYPE, size )
    Storage::set__( Rf_allocVector( RTYPE, size) ) ;
    fill_or_generate( u ) ;
}
```

And that `fill_or_generate` function would eventually dispatch down [here](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h#L1001-L1006):

```
template <typename T>
inline void fill_or_generate__impl( const T& gen, traits::true_type) {
    iterator first = begin() ;
    iterator last = end() ;
    while( first != last ) *first++ = gen() ;
}
```

So we can see that a (templated) generator function is supplied to fill the vector, and the corresponding `operator()` of the `gen` object is used to populate the vector -- ie, in this case, the `stats::UnifGenerator` object.

So then, the question is, how does it all come together in this call?

```
NumericVector x = runif(10);
```

I always forget this for some reason, but I believe this is basically copy-construction of `x` from the result of the `runif(10)` call, but this point is also elaborated on by @nrussell. But, my understanding:

1. `runif` generates a `NumericVector` of length 10 with `runif` elements -- call this temporary right-hand object `tmp`,
2. `x` is copy-constructed to be the same as the aforementioned `tmp`.

I believe that compilers will be able to elide that copy construction, so that `x` is in fact directly constructed from the result of `runif(10)` and so should be efficient (at least, at any reasonable optimization level), but I could be wrong ....

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Having the implementation detail could also be help in the future.